# How to delete all files in parent folder with same file name as in a specified subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I am new to batch file writing.
This is the current content of parent folder `Folder1`:

```
C:\Folder1\Subfolder1
C:\Folder1\Afile001.txt
C:\Folder1\Bfile002.txt
C:\Folder1\Cfile003.txt
C:\Folder1\Xfile004.txt
C:\Folder1\Yfile005.txt
```

The number of files increases from time to time in this folder.

I need the current list of files from `Folder1` and then copy them to `Subfolder1` which is achieved by using command `copy *.txt Subfolder1`.

Next the files in `Subfolder1` are taken (or copied) by some process and then contents of parent `Folder1` changes to:

```
C:\Folder1\Subfolder1
C:\Folder1\Afile001.txt
C:\Folder1\Bfile002.txt
C:\Folder1\Cfile003.txt
C:\Folder1\Xfile004.txt
C:\Folder1\Yfile005.txt
C:\Folder1\Dfile001.txt
C:\Folder1\Efile002.txt
C:\Folder1\Ffile003.txt
C:\Folder1\Gfile004.txt
C:\Folder1\Hfile005.txt
```

How can I achieve a batch file which takes the list of files from `Subfolder1` and use that list to delete the files with same name from `Folder1` and leaves behind only the new files in that folder?

So the result should be for `Folder1`:

```
C:\Folder1\Subfolder1
C:\Folder1\Dfile001.txt
C:\Folder1\Efile002.txt
C:\Folder1\Ffile003.txt
C:\Folder1\Gfile004.txt
C:\Folder1\Hfile005.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with just a single command line using the commands **FOR** and **DEL**:

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("C:\Folder1\Subfolder1\*.txt") do del "C:\Folder1\%%~nxI" 2>nul
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` to suppress the error message output by **DEL** to handle **STDERR** with redirection to device **NUL** in case of a *.txt file in `C:\Folder1\Subfolder1` does not exist anymore in `C:\Folder1`.

By the way: It would be also possible to use the command

```
move /Y C:\Folder1\*.txt C:\Folder1\Subfolder1\
```

to move the files from `C:\Folder1` to `C:\Folder1\Subfolder1` instead of copying them first and later deleting them.